# SQLAlchemy + cx_oracle and special characters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I'm attempting to connect to an oracle db with SQLAlchemmy:

```
import sqlalchemy

oracle_db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:passwd@host:port/schema')
connection = oracle_db.connect()

result = connection.execute("SELECT sysdate from dual")

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

However I'm getting the following error on line 3:

```
TypeError: makedsn() takes no keyword arguments
```

Is there something wrong with this?

**Important note (please don't ask why):** the password is something among the lines of:

```
A(sdf)1234
```

Do the parenthesis cause this?

Answer (score 1):

That error implies you are using an older version of cx_Oracle. Keyword parameters were added to that method in 5.1.1. The latest version is 5.2.1 which you can acquire from here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/